Curacao Visa restrictions
I'm a UK citizen currently living in Curacao and was wondering after 90 or 180 days I can leave the country for a few days and fly back in to reset?
I worked on a Yacht in Costa Rica before and once my 3 months was up I just had to go to Nicaragua for a few days to get my passport re-stamped.
Can I do this here?

Since you have not stated your citizenship, no definate answer can be given, but based on the information contained here: Do I need a visa to visit Curaçao? (for a period of maximum 30 consecutive days, with a maximum of 90 days in a 180-day period. Dutch and US nationalities are allowed to stay 180 consecutive days in any 365-day period.), your idea will not work.

But it worked in Costa rica and thats the same? Im currently working  on a permit but could take 8 months...

Thsnk you for your reply though :)

Costa Rica is not Curaçao, laws are different and the way the laws are followed might be different again.

@user166142, different countries have different rules. Curacao and Costa Rica are different countries.

Costa Rica has no any x-day period in their conditions. Curaçao does. This generelly means that you may only remain for a certain amount of days per 180/360 period. For Costa Rica you were lucky that the immigration official didn't notice that you were performing a 'visa run'. They could just have well refused you entry since: For a stay longer than 180 days a residence permit must be established.(Embassy of Costa Rica)

I'm a UK citizen. Just waiting on a work permit which could take months.

According to gov.uk, you can request an extension beyond 90 days at immigration if you can show you have travel insurance for the duration of your extended stay.

@Traveller they then link to the official NL site which has no mention of that extension possibility. Also they say 90 days per year when it’s actually 90/180. Probably not up to date?

No you can't.
What you are describing is often referred to as a "visa run". Some countries have no explicit rules against a tourist going to another country at the end of his stay and returning shortly afterwards to reset the timer (I guess Costa Rica is one of them). Whether this works in practice is a different story. A border agent could notice the pattern and refuse entry. However, Curaçao have a specific rule to prevent visa runs, according to the official website:

If you do not need a visa to travel to the Caribbean parts of the
Kingdom, you can stay for a maximum of 90 days in a 180-day period.

And as a UK national you do not need a visa.
